# Ассемблерные вставки

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте.

Возник вопрос, по поводу ассемблерных вставок, а именно, как часто их стоит использовать. Нужно стараться как можно большую часть функционала реализовывать при помощи языка ассемблера или какие-то отдельные моменты, которые, к примеру, требуют большого количества вычислений?

Предлагаю поразмышлять на эту тему, если конечно, это вам интересно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше использование ассемблерных вставок свести к минимуму, поскольку это как минимум влияет на переносимость кода. Если речь идет об оптимизации, то не факт, что это поможет, поскольку современные компиляторы (говорю о С и С++) очень неплохо умеют оптимизировать код. Написать вручную более быстрый код как правило очень непросто.
Вставки используются в основном при ядерном программировании для низкоуровневого доступа к оборудованию, которое недоступно средствами более высоких языков, или для оптимизации, но о ней смотри выше.

Comment: Узкие места (bottleneck'и) в программах для микроконтроллеров (преимущественно 8-ми-разрядных. В остальных случаях -- нафиг, нафиг.

Comment: Т.е. очень узкий круг специальных задач.

Comment: IMHO вставки надо применять практически только для доступа к оборудованию и командам процессора типа чтение-запись управляющих регистров.

Если хотите что-то специфически эффективное во внутренних циклах, то все равно выделяйте в отдельную функцию на ассемблере.

Comment: @avp, это все опять же относится к привилегированному режиму, т.е. к ядру, к обычными программам это не относится.

Comment: Не всегда

    #define cpuid(func,ax,bx,cx,dx)\
 __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid":\
 "=a" (ax), "=b" (bx), "=c" (cx), "=d" (dx) : "a" (func));

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;

  cpuid(1,a,b,c,d);

  printf ("%x %x %x %x\n",a,b,c,d);
  
  if (d & (1<<18))
    printf ("pn\n");
  if (d & (1<<19))
    printf ("clflush\n");
  if (d & (1<<23))
    printf ("mmx\n");
  if (d & (1<<25))
    printf ("sse\n");
  if (d & (1<<26))
    printf ("sse2\n");
  if (d & (1<<28))
    printf ("htt\n");


}

Некоторык флаги процессора x86 из user mode

Comment: @avp Только где тут функция, когда макрос. Вот и вспомнишь Watcom C/C++ с его ассемблерными вставками в виде inline-функций. А в случае bottleneck'а добавлять вызов функции некошерно.

Comment: @avp, а где здесь 

    для доступа к оборудованию и командам процессора типа чтение-запись управляющих регистров

?

Comment: @mikillskegg, так `cpuid` же.

Comment: @alexlz, совершенно верно, зто не функция, а ассемблерная вставка (оформленная через макрос). И причем здесь функции ? 

Комментарий  с ней это ответ на комментарий @mikillskegg о привилегированном режиме.